# Notes 9 client doesn't display inline images as before

Tags: lotus-notes

We have an application that displays photos of employees. The images are uploaded from files and rendered inline via a NotesStream.SetContentFromBytes. The field in Designer is regular Rich Text, not stored as HTML/MIME. The NotesStream creates a new MIMEEntity.

In the 9 Standard client, the image is seen as an attachment, not inline. In the 9 browser client, it's inline. In versions before 9 (i.e. 8.5.3) it's inline. Viewing the same document at the same time in different clients show the same - attachment in 9 standard, inline image in the others. If I manually copy an image and past it in, then save the document it gets converted to an attachment (9 standard).

I made a copy of the database, changed the Rich Text field to store as HTML/MIME, and ran the import. It's still an attachment.

It seems that this is a difference in how the Notes 9 standard client is rendering inline images. I've called Notes support, but I wanted to post and see if anyone else has seen this or perhaps have a thought.

Cheers,
Brian

Comment: Did you probably set ShowMIMEImagesAsAttachments=1 in the notes.ini of your client (probably with a policy), that would cause the described behaviour...

Comment: No policy, and that entry is not in my ini file. Putting it in and trying 1 and 0 has no effect.

Comment: This may be related to my observation, that image resources in Designer are stored as MIME, compared to plain attachments in previous versions. IBM might change something in guts of Notes. I would like to hear what support says to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this to IBM, and it should be fixed in 9.0.2, or that is the plan now. I'm not sure what was different about the rendering, but the numbers:

APAR #LO75973 /  SPR #PJON9926PN 
If and when this is fixed, the APAR and SPR will be listed in the fix list database. 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/SPR?OpenView

Cheers,
Brian